# How to countdown and count up forever endlessly

Tags: python

```
i = 10
while i>=1:
    print("count down in " + str(i))
    i = i - 1 #or i +=1

if i<10:
    print("blasting off")

    if i==0:
    print("ready in " +str(i))

while i<=10:
    print("starting up in " + str(i))
    i +=1
```

## how to reloop this endlessly like 10 to 0 than 0 to 10 forever

Comment: just stick a while True around it?

Answer (score 0):

Put your two loops inside an infinite outer loop, for example:

```
while True:
    for i in range(10,1,-1):
        print(i)

    for i in range(1,10):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python there is an easy way to do endless cycles. You can use the while(True), which will be always true. I hope this helped.

```
i = 10
temp = True
while(True):
    i = 10
    while i>=1:
        print("count down in " + str(i)
        i -= 1

        if i<10:
            print("blasting off")

            if i==0:
                print("ready in " +str(i))

    while i<=10:
        print("starting up in " + str(i))
        i +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count_up = 0
count_down = 10
while True:
    count_up += 1
    count_down -= 1
    print("Count_up: ", count_up)
    print("Count_down:", count_down)
    if count_up == 10:  # once it counts up to 10 reset to 0 
       count_up = 0
    if count_down == 0: # once it dounts down to 0 reset to 10
       count_down = 10
```

This will go up 10 and down 10 endlessley

or if you just want to use 1 variable in this case i:

```
i = 10
while True:
    print(i)
    i -= 1 
    if i == 0:
        for j in range(10):
            print(i)
            i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This one here uses a generator, which is a construct in python that `yield`s values whenever asked for the `next` one. The cool thing about it is that you can separate your value generation logic from your other code using these values (even if it's just a `print`). This helped me before in cases where the code got too entangled to understand easily.

```py
def triangle(vmax):
    """ Generator that yields values of a periodic triangle function between 0 to vmax,
    starting at vmax. """    
    # init states
    v = vmax - 1      # the last generated value
    rising = True     # indicates the current direction

    # now yield values forever
    while True:
        if v == vmax:
            rising = False
        elif v == 0:
            rising = True

        v += 1 if rising else -1
        yield v


t = triangle(10)        # create the generator...
vals = [next(t) for i in range(30)]  # ... now get 30 values from it
print(vals)
```